# How to hide the Horizontal Scroll bar

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have 2 APEX interactive grids as a master detail on the same page.  The top grid (master) has a vertical scroll bar which I want but there are only a few columns in each row and it does not need a horizontal bar.

I had to change the Pagination to scroll from Page and set the heading to region and the height to 400 px so both reports are displayed on one page.

I tried setting body overflow to hide in template options but I still have a big horizontal scroll bar in the middle of my page.

In addition to this, it seems the columns keep resizing themselves to take up all the space even though I made them very small and saved the report.  The scroll bar does not really scroll since it has no place to go.

[image]

Any help on how to get rid of the scroll bar would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know it's a bit of work, but are you able to reproduce this on apex.oracle.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to hide it is for the columns to be smaller so that there is no reason for it to exist(afaik). You say you already resized them and saved the report and it didn't work. I am not sure if it will work but we have this code in the attributes-advanced-javascript initialisation code in one of out environments that seems to do what you want:

```
function(config) {
    // Logically we want to do this: config.views.grid.features.stretchColumns = false;
    // but the server may not generate the views, grid, or features objects
    // so we must check for and add if needed each one using this code
    var o = config;
    "views.grid.features".split(".").forEach(function(p) { 
        if ( !o[p] ) {
            o[p] = {};
        }
        o = o[p];
    });
    o.stretchColumns = false;
    return config;
}
```

Try it and maybe it will work for you, not a guaranteed answer, but just something to try.